# Alignement of keys with subscripts in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to get better control over the text in a table.

In the following minimal example the keys of the table are A A_c, A_c and abc. but A in the first column and A_c in the second column are not aligned correctly as they are in the key of the first column. Instead, the subscript c in the first key is aligned with A in the second key, creating a bad visual effect and lifting effectively the keys with respect to one another:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)

col_labels=[r'A \textbf{A}\boldmath$_c$',r'\textbf{A}',r'\textbf{abc}']
row_labels=[r'\textbf{a}',r'\textbf{b}',r'\textbf{abc}']
table_vals=[['-','-','-'],['-','-','-'],['-','-','-']]
the_table = plt.table(cellText=table_vals,
              rowLabels=row_labels,
              colLabels=col_labels,
              loc='center',  colWidths = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1] , cellLoc='bottom')
the_table.scale(1,3.5)
the_table.set_fontsize(44)
plt.show()
```

How can be the text aligned differently?

Comment: One solution I found is leaving the key blank and use the matplotlib.annotate method to insert text, alligning it manually. Quite time consuming as a solution...